# Changing b2_velocity threshold in an existing Swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, box2d

I am working on an iOS game using Swift and SpriteKit. It involves collisions between two or more SKShapeNodes that have physics bodies that go along with them.

My problem is that when they collide, if they are going too slow, the collisions are treated as inelastic and rather than bouncing they "stick" to each other so to speak.

From numerous searches, I believe I've found the problem to be in the underlying physics engine which is Box2d. There is a defined constant 'b2_velocityThreshold' that is set to 1.0f and if a collision happens at speeds under that threshold, I run into the issue stated.

How do I go about changing that value to a number that would help maintain the elastic collisions? I'm not sure how to access the files and be able to update that value. Would I need to download the Box2d library and then connect that into my project somehow? Or would I need to restart and import that from the start? and build the project in C++ from the beginning because Box2d is written in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sprite Kit you can't change any of the box2d parameters because there's no source code for Sprite Kit and the version of Box2d that Apple used to build Sprite Kit with. You will have to make the game work with whatever parameters are exposed by the Sprite Kit API.

One thing you can try: set friction of the two slow moving bodies to 0. This may preserve their energy (velocities) when colliding.